# PostgreSQL porblema con clusters man pg_createcluster

Tags: sql

tengo un problema al iniciar el servidor de debian el 
cual me arroja una alerta mediante se inicia.

No PostgresSQL clusters exist: see "man pg_createcluster" .. (warning)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no es una respuesta definitiva pero debido a que no tengo la reputaciön necesaria no puedo comentar. Te sugeriría que verificaras que el servicio de PostgreSQL encuentra la ruta donde usualmente se encuentra instalado el cluster por defecto (puede variar dependiendo de la plataforma pero suele ser /var/lib/postgresql/XX/main).